# ThreadPool on Android through mono, seemingly not "pooling"

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, mono, threadpool

I'm using ThreadPool on an application I'm developing for mobile, Android and iOS. I'm developing this application using Unity. So it's the ThreadPool from the .net mono library (.net 3.5 I believe) and all coded in the lovely C#.

Loving ThreadPool, finding it very useful breaking things away from the main unity thread to give me more liberty in synchronous operations.

I've made myself a static class to help monitor what's going on and keep track of the threads I'm using, to help diagnose possible problems, and catch exceptions to make me aware of them during development. (See code below)

```
public static class ITThreadPool {
    private static Dictionary<Thread, string> threads = new Dictionary<Thread, string>();

    public static void QueueUserWorkItem(Action<object> item){
        int rndId = new Random().Next(50);
        LogInfo(1, "Task requested: {0}", rndId);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state) {
            LogInfo(1, "Task executed: {0}", rndId);

            try{
                Thread current = Thread.CurrentThread;
                if(threads.ContainsKey(current)){
                    LogInfo(0, "Thread recycled: {0}", current.ManagedThreadId);
                }else{
                    threads.Add(current, "STARTED");
                    LogInfo(0, "Thread created: {0}", current.ManagedThreadId);
                }

                item(state);

                SetTaskNameForThisThread("returned");
            }catch(System.Exception ex){
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Exception executing task. See console for details");
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogException(ex);

                SetTaskNameForThisThread("Ended after unhandled exception "+ex.ToString());

                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void PrintDetails(){
        string threadLog = threads.Count;

        int wt;
        int cpt;
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out wt, out cpt);
        threadLog += string.Format("\nMax worker threads: {0} completion port threads: {1}", wt, cpt);

        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out wt, out cpt);
        threadLog += string.Format("\nAvailable worker threads: {0} completion port threads: {1}", wt, cpt);


        foreach (KeyValuePair<Thread, string> thread in threads)    
        {
            threadLog += string.Format("\nID: {0} State: {1} Last task update: {2}", thread.Key.ManagedThreadId, thread.Key.ThreadState, thread.Value);
        }

        LogInfo(2, threadLog);
    }

    public static void SetTaskNameForThisThread(string name){
        Thread ct = Thread.CurrentThread;
        if(threads.ContainsKey(ct)){
            threads[ct] = name;
        }
    }

    private static void LogInfo(int subjectId, string info, params object[] args){
        string color;
        if(subjectId == 0){
            color = "blue";
        }else if(subjectId == 1){
            color = "orange";
        }else{
            color = "green";
        }
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(string.Format("<color={0}>THREAD TRACKING -------------------------------- </color>", color)+string.Format(info, args));
    }
```

I keep track of my created threads, when they start, when they end, and catch exceptions so that during development I can log them (otherwise outside the unity thread, no errors are logged, this helps me track em down!)

I have a means of giving a thread a task label with "SetTaskNameForThisThread" so that if a thread get's blocked or something, I can try to track down where.

Then I have "PrintDetails" that can tell me all about whats happening, how many thread instances have been used, how many threads are available and what tasks threads are doing or if they've finished thanks to the task label.

This seems to work well in the editor on Mac OS X. I never have more than 4 or 5 Thread instances in the "threads" dictionary.

But, in Android, the list gets bigger and bigger and bigger! They all get assigned the label "returned" so they've all executed and finished, but aren't being "recycled" and reused by new tasks.

I expect it comes from the way android handles it's threads(?) and it's more of an observational question then a problem.

My questions are:

1. Is this a problem? Or should I not care and let it do it's thing.
2. If it is a problem, how can I / is it possible to resolve it?
3. My app sometimes completely freezes, I think it is due to a 3rd party framework I'm using, though I may be (and probably am) completely wrong, could it come from this? It could come from deadlock or race condition. But it only occurs on android and it is the unity thread that freezes (and that thread is independent of all this noise) so could this be the cause?

Thanks for reading, look forward to learning lots from your responses responses on this, in my opinion, interesting subject.

Thanks !

Regards,
Beau